# Default tooltip is not shown to disabled window using win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to find a way to show tooltip even if we disable window like this:

```
EnableWindow(hWnd, false);
```

Here is how I am creating tooltip:

```
void CreateTooltip(HWND hparent)
{
    HWND hwndTT = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP, 0, 0, 0, 0, hparent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    TTTOOLINFO ti = { 0 };

    //ti.cbSize = sizeof(TTTOOLINFO);
    //*********************************************************
    // Specific settings for specific compiler options (Unicode/VC2013)
    //*********************************************************
    ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V2_SIZE;

    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = hparent;

    ti.lpszText = (LPWSTR)(L"Tooltip string");
    GetClientRect(hparent, &ti.rect);

    if (!SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ti))
        MessageBox(0, TEXT("Failed: TTM_ADDTOOL"), 0, 0);
}
```

I want to have two tooltips, one for enabled state and one for disabled.
Maybe there is a way to avoid this limitation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to Implement Tracking Tooltips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/implement-tracking-tooltips).

Comment: I'm afraid that with when (the window is disabled) the container of the ToolTip is not active they mean when the container of the ToolTip does not have focus. So the tooltip gets hidden as well.